# Deleting Closed Questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Deletion of closed questions is not happening to the extent required. Although the Review Tab for users with enough reputation is available, few of us are actually going in and deleting stuff.

I think the problem was aggravated after we got the review pane with closed & reopen questions. We seem to forget to delete the questions.

Another issue is that recent changes (say, about a year ago?) don't allow closed questions to be deleted for 2 days, because we want to give OP the opportunity to edit and reopen the question. By this time, we forget about the question.

Maybe one solution is to have "Delete" questions in the review list.

- [Current list of closed questions](https://money.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=close&daterange=last30days)
- We had discussed this some time back and agreed not to delete questions marked "Duplicate" as they may bring in traffic. The question is at **[Deleting Closed Question of No Value is not happening](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/415/deleting-closed-question-of-no-value-is-not-happening)**.

Comment: Ay!  I have been ignoring the delete queue.  ChrisWRea used to stay on top of that. I just purged a bunch of garbage.  I did elect to keep some closed items that are still newish and salvageable, or just plain popular questions.

Comment: That's right -- I used to delete closed questions every so often. I'd browse [this query](http://money.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20closed%3a1) and tended to delete closed questions more than a week or two old where the question wasn't closed as a duplicate [duplicates use alternative keywords and can be good for search engines to find the content another way]. Closed questions of historical significance or where the closed status was under dispute (e.g. recent edits and/or reopen votes present) typically got a pass for a while.

Comment: @MrChrister & Chris W. Rea, as moderators you can step in. However people with enough rep can also vote for delete. I am requesting all people with enough rep to participate in the delete process.

Comment: I'd spend a few minutes now and then on this effort if I had an easier search. Chris' link shows the questions, but I need to click though each before finding I already voted. A regular interface like the "review" button showing only questions that I've not touched but can vote to delete, is what would help.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Another place to look is [here](http://money.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=Delete&daterange=last30days), then click on "Most Votes" to expand and see what others have been voting to delete recently, so you might throw your vote in too. Still not what you are looking for, but at least it avoids having to go through all the duplicates in the other report link I mentioned (mind you, I notice some folks are voting to delete closed-as-duplicate questions, which, IMHO, we should leave around for SEO keyword purposes.)