# I answered a question a couple of years ago and now it's gone

Tags: support, answers, reputation

I just saw this question on the HNQ list [Is it a good idea to copy a trader when investing?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/108682/33511).

This reminded me of an answer I had given to a question on this site a couple of years ago. The question was something like "Do forex signals provide any value?".

In my answer I essentially said they don't. And I advised training on trading psychology or something else.

My answer was well received (that I remember); had upvotes, and if I'm not mistaken, was even accepted by the OP.

Now I can't seem to find it.
My reputation graph does not display any sign there was ever such an answer.
It appears to be completely gone and I was not notified at all.

**I'm sure it was still on this site as of this year (2019).**

Where is the Q/A and what happened to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an excellent memory. The question "[Do live forex signal services work](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/54259/do-live-forex-signal-services-work)?" was closed as offtopic. For what it's worth, 5 members all "closed as primarily opinion-based" and more recently, it was deleted as there was no way to edit to salvage it.

This all occurs with no notice, and had nothing to do with your answer, just an off topic question.

Comment: Ah. Not excellent, not as many upvotes as I thought. Thanks for finding it. I would hope to be notified when that happens, but this is a matter to discuss elsewhere.

Comment: May I ask a quick follow-up question: Are questions that are closed as off-topic always deleted, even when they have answers?

Comment: @Marc.2377 That is a matter that has [recently been discussed on meta](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2662/10997).

Comment: Yes, you can. We have other meta-discussions about the disposition of closed questions. In general, a recently closed question can be edited to be made on topic. At times, the question is in the gray area and some minor edits help to make the question get re-opened. Other questions sit for a long time in that status and can remain that way in definitely. Some questions bubble back up by a member voting to delete which puts that question in the queue for others to vote on. In this case it hit the queue to Delete and I agreed, there was really no fixing this question.

Comment: Let me add something else. Voting should not be taken as an ironclad indication of whether a question is on topic. It is very possible for an off-topic question to hit the Hot network question Queue. From those visitors alone, we can have a highly voted question and highly voted answers to a question that is ultimately off-topic. They debate on meta surrounds the issue of whether it’s fair to destroy somebody’s honest work from an answer that may ultimately be deleted because the question should not have been posted. The issue is ongoing.

Comment: I understand. Thanks for clarifying.